# How does primary slots and secondary vrf slots work?

Tags: validator, block-production, fork, block-time

I am struggling to understand some behaviour on a custom `7 validators solochain`.

Currently using babe with a `1/4 primary slots probability`, the `block time is 20 sec`, and we have `PrimaryAndSecondaryPlainSlots` as allowed slots.

Things i'm wondering :

> - While adding log the babe module, I computed a real primary probability of arround 22.5% instead of 25% (on a "relatively small"
>   sample of 10000 blocks).
> - Also on the network, I notice a lot of fork / uncles set.
> - The most problematic is this morning, I saw that a slot was missed (both primary and secondary) and the time between two block was twice
>   what it should be (40 seconds instead of 20)

**Is this a normal behaviour ? Is there an actual probability of missing a slot to produce a block ?**

Usefull links :

- [Config](https://github.com/availproject/avail/blob/develop/runtime/src/constants.rs#L323-L326)
- [Network explorer](https://kate.avail.tools/#/staking)
- [Block](https://kate.avail.tools/#/explorer/query/33525) - [Parent block](https://kate.avail.tools/#/explorer/query/0x744e952ebddb37919e8a82e76f9e1494a465d8475732b2ae00c8da44332da9e0)
- [Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWHOw.png)